# How to implement lazy loading of a PDF file using Java code?

Tags: java, pdf

If I use the PDDocument.load() method directly, it will load the entire PDF file into memory, which does not meet my requirements. Because my PDF file is on a remote server with limited bandwidth, loading everything at once will take a long time. Therefore, I want to load only a part of it, such as the first 10 pages, to speed up the viewing of the PDF. After I finish viewing the first 10 pages, I can then load the next 10 pages and so on.

There is an Android app called "Comit Screen" which implements similar functionality, but I don't know how it achieves this.

Comment: The [LEADTOOLS PDF SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf) has the [PDFFile](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pdf/pdffile.html) Class which can be used to [extract a separate page](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pdf/pdffile-extractpages(int,int,string).html) from the original PDF as well as [streamline and linearize](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pdf/pdffile-linearize.html) the file in general for optimal viewing. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)